# PrettyFaces url routing from form submit

Tags: jsf-2, prettyfaces

I'm using Pretty Faces to do URL rewriting, in order to be able to reuse some xhtml files.  I'd like to have URLs like '/honda/index.xhtml' and '/toyota/index.xhtml' both go to the same /make/index.xhtml file, with the make coming in as a parameter.  This routing seems to work OK with a config like this:

```
<url-mapping id="carMake">
    <pattern value="/#{make}/index.xhtml"></pattern>
    <view-id value="/make/index.xhtml"/>
</url-mapping>
```

I also have this mapping for a search results type of page:

```
<url-mapping id="search">
    <pattern value="/#{make}/search/index.xhtml" />
    <view-id value="/search/index.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

Both of these work as expected when I manually put the URL in the browser.

I run into a problem when I try to put a form on the first page, that I want to redirect to the second page.  I have this jsf xhtml code for a form:

```
<h:form>
    <h:messages />
    <h:inputText id="searchTerm"/>
    <h:commandButton value="search" action="/honda/search/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"/>
</h:form>
```

(hard coding /honda here to simplify the example)

When I try to submit this search, it bounces back to the same /honda/index.xhtml, with no messages being displayed on the page.

The logs show this:

```
09-23 11:39:55 DEBUG PrettyNavigationHandler:57 - Navigation requested: fromAction [/honda/search/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true], outcome [/honda/search/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true]
09-23 11:39:55 DEBUG PrettyNavigationHandler:60 - Not a PrettyFaces navigation string - passing control to default nav-handler
```

I've tried without the faces-redirect param, but got the same result.

Why does /honda/search/index.xhtml work when I put it into the browser directly, but not as the result of an action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use separate the URL from the View ID, and you don't want to reference the view-id in the app, then you need to use pretty navigation strings:

`<h:commandButton value="search" 
           action="pretty:honda"><f:param name="make" value="honda" /></h:commandLink>`

But this really is just making it more complicated than it needs to be. I would recommend doing what @chkal suggested, except his example is a little wrong. It should have been:

`<h:commandButton value="search" 
           action="/search/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&make=honda"/>`

This should be covered in the docs :) http://ocpsoft.org/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.3/en-US/html/components.html#components.prettylink Check that section (and the ones below it) and see if that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a pretty URL as a value for the action attribute this way. You have to use a standard JSF outcome with `make` being a query parameter.

Try this:

```
<h:commandButton value="search" 
           action="/honda/search/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&make=honda"/>
```

Comment: It's a good answer, although not the one I was hoping for, since it defeats the purpose of what I was hoping to get out of PrettyFaces

Comment: If you want to use separate the URL from the View ID, and you don't want to reference the view-id in the app, then you need to use pretty navigation strings: `<h:commandButton value="search" 
           action="pretty:honda"><f:param name="make" value="honda" /></h:commandLink>`, but this really is just making it more complicated than it needs to be. I would recommend doing what @chkal suggested, except his example is a little wrong. It should have been: `<h:commandButton value="search" 
           action="/search/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&make=honda"/>`